# I am trying to display avatars generated with faker.js but when I try to load the avatar in a bootstrap card an error is shown in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I just used *faker.js* to generate random information such as name, email, phone, etc, and avatar. When I try to show the information generated by *faker* and the avatars, which are like this:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/j2deme/128.jpg
I get a message telling me the following:

> 128.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

This message is shown in the console. Why is this happening? Any advice? Thanks in advance.

I am expecting to visualize the image from the URL in a bootstrap card.